# CreateDirectory windows API usage in c++ to create a directory under C:/users without running the application as an admin

Tags: c++, windows, api, subdirectory, mkdir

I want my program to create a directory under "C:\users\" using "CreateDirectory()" function:

```
#include<windows.h>

int main(){
   CreateDirectory ("C:\\Users\\mndir", NULL);
   return 0;
}
```

The problem is that it fails to create a directory under "C:/users" if we did not run the application as admin.

Is there a solution for this problem without running the application as an admin?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider using std::filesystem::create_directory() (since C++17)

Comment: Your backslashes suggest that you are trying to create “C:\Usersmndir” (assuming that your compiler ignores backslashes that don’t form known escape sequences).

Comment: Thanks Davis; I forgot this backslash while writing the question. I updated it.

Comment: Creating new subdirectories there requires administrator privileges. That's the directory where user profiles are created, and only administrators can do that.

Comment: C:\Users is protected by UAC. You need elevation to do this.

Comment: The way this question is worded puzzles me greatly.  So, if there was some function that can create a folder under `C:\Users`, without requiring admin privileges, but it was not the `CreateDirectory()` function, then would you not consider that as a solution to your problem?  Furthermore, why do you want to create a directory under `C:\Users`?  Could it be that what you *actually* want to do is create...  ***a user***?

Comment: For the first point: yes, I would consider it a solution as I'm searching for a function that can create a directory under "C:/Users" without requiring admin privilege. For the second point: I do want to create a directory under "C:/Users" as the application that I'm working on porting it does so! Thus, it is a legacy tool and we need to keep the backward compatibility.

Comment: You can have the program's installer (which is running as administrator) pre-create the necessary directories and set the security on them appropriately. Note however that creating directories inside C:\Users is highly irregular and may cause problems with future profile creation. Better would be to fix the tool so it uses some other directory.

Comment: If it's a Unix application that creates a directory in "/home", surely you can abstract this to use some other directory that's a better fit to Windows, such as "C:\ProgramData\<organization>\mndir". Your installer can create this directory and set appropriate security for users to access it. Actually, it can be created lazily on first use as well, since the creator has full control to set security on the directory.